# Perl Issue trying to add static text by IP address

Tags: perl

I have a script that has an exact count of IP address' being compared to an expected count of IP address going though a specific port.

Code:

```
my %minimum = (
    '10.10.10.10' => 2,
    '10.10.10.11' => 3,
    '10.10.10.12' => 6,
    '10.10.10.13' => 7,
);
my %count;

open my $fh, '-|', 'netstat -an |grep 1111 ' or die "could not run netstat: $!";
while(<$fh>) {
    next unless /^\s*............(regex) /;
    $count{$1}++;
}
close $fh;

while(my ($ip, $expected) = each %minimum) {
    $count{$ip} ||= 0;
    next if $count{$ip} == $expected && print color("green"), "$ip: OK! Expected = $expected count =  $count{$ip}\n", color("reset");
    print color("red"), "$ip: BAD! Expected = $expected count =  $count{$ip}\n", color("reset");
}
```

I'm trying to add a static hostname. Currently an example output looks like:

```
10.10.10.10: OK! Expected = 2 Actual =  2
10.10.10.11: OK! Expected = 3 Actual =  3
10.10.10.12: OK! Expected = 6 Actual =  6
10.10.10.13: BAD! Expected = 7 Actual =  5
```

But I want to include a static hostname to look like below:

```
10.10.10.10: aaaa@aa.com OK! Expected = 2 Actual =  2
10.10.10.11: bbb@aa.com OK! Expected = 3 Actual =  3
10.10.10.12: ccc@aa.com OK! Expected = 6 Actual =  6
10.10.10.13: ddd@aa.com BAD! Expected = 7 Actual =  5
```

Thank you all for any recommendations/tips.

Comment: Your "static hostname" doesn't look static, or like a hostname, and it's not clear where the information is supposed to come from.

Comment: @hobbs the 10.10.10.10 "count" is pulled from the netstat -an.... the hostname isn't pulled from anywhere. example 10.10.10.10 = cheeseburgers.

Comment: Again, where does `cheeseburgers` come from?

Comment: You can use `dig` to perform a reverse lookup for you.  `dig -x 8.8.8.8`

Comment: @ikegami I think I'm explaining this terribly. cheeseburgers doesn't come from anywhere, I just want to include the word `cheeseburgers` after the ip address `10.10.10.10` as an example. My whole goal is to have more information about each IP address in "my `%minimum`

Comment: But what if the address isn't 10.10.10.10. How do you determine what to use then?

Comment: Thanks @xxfelixxx for your suggestion. I'm not looking for a reverse dns lookup. I'm trying manually add each hostname next to each IP address without pulling It from anywhere. another example would be `10.10.10.10: this_is_a_dallas_connection OK! Expected = 2 Actual =  2`
`10.10.10.11: this_is_a_georga_connection OK! Expected = 3 Actual =  3`

Comment: @ikegami I'm trying to set each IP with a note. in the example above the output would say `10.10.10.10 cheeseburger OK! Expected = 2 Actual =  2` 
`10.10.10.11 hotdog OK! Expected = 3 Actual =  3`

Comment: What's the note for 10.10.10.12?

Comment: What's the note for 10.10.10.13?

Comment: You realize there are 4 billion different IPv4 addresses. This is going to take a long time to get this info from you unless you tell us where these notes are coming from.

Comment: @ikegami because I already know where the connection is coming from. so `10.10.10.10` always comes from a dallas connection. `10.10.10.11` always comes from a georga connection. `10.10.10.12` always comes form an Nebraska connection. So the note comes from my own understanding of where the connection is coming from

Comment: @ikegami there are only 4 possible IP addressing coming into a single port number. those IP's will only be `10.10.10.10` `10.10.10.11` `10.10.10.12` and `10.10.10.13` which I'm just trying to put a note of what each of the 4 possible ip address represents.

Comment: Your statement `next if $count{$ip} == $expected && print color("green"), ...` does `next if $count{$ip} == ( $expected && print color("green"), ...)` so it will pretty much always compare `$count{$ip}` to 1. You could use `and` instead of `&&`, but I would prefer to see `if ( $count{$ip} == $expected ) { print color("green"), ...; next; }` (on multiple lines).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a second hash to keep the info, keyed on the ip addresses, or you could create a nested data structure like so:

```
my %minimum = (
    '10.10.10.10' => { label => 'hotdog', count => 2 },
    '10.10.10.11' => { label => 'burger', count => 3 },
    '10.10.10.12' => { label => 'steak',  count => 6 },
    '10.10.10.13' => { label => 'pizza',  count => 7 },
);
```

and then later, when you need the info, you can retrieve it:

```
while(my ($ip, $data) = each %minimum) {
    $count{$ip} ||= 0;
    my $label = $data->{label};
    my $expected = $data->{count};
    # ... rest of code here ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This solution is very clear and works great. I tried to up-vote but my account is too new. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

```
my %notes = (
   '10.10.10.10' => 'cheeseburger',
   '10.10.10.11' => 'hotdog',
   '10.10.10.12' => '...',
   '10.10.10.13' => '...',
);

s{^([^:]*):\K}{ defined($notes{$1}) ? " $notes{$1}" : "" }e;
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Comment: @Toby Speight, Did you find an actual problem, or are you one of those that believe in adding comments like "this is a substitute operator"? If it's the former, identify the issue and I'll be happy to expand on it. If on the other hand you believe on adding comments for the sake of adding comments, then I find that detrimental.

Comment: Oh no, just repeating the code in words is pointless.  I'm more interested in *why* this is a good solution.  I can see that it's a lot more compact; perhaps that's the most relevant point.  It might also be worth mentioning the care you've taken to accept both found and unfound results.  Really, what makes this a better answer than any other?

Comment: Re "*I'm more interested in why this is a good solution.*", Because it works, it's clean, and self-explanatory. I don't see myself adding that to the question.